# How to change the cursor shape while dragging over other controls?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, drag-and-drop

I have basically two controls involved in a drag/drop operation. I do this for the start control:

```
private void controlA_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventsArgs e)
{
  if(e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
  {
    //set DataObject...datao
    DragDrop.DoDragDrop(controlB, datao, DragDropEffects.Copy | DragDropEffects.Copy;
   }
}
```

The user moves off of controlA, onto controlB and continues dragging to some point on controlB. I've tried the following in several events with no luck to establish a different cursor from the default arrow with the little box under it:

```
Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Hand;
```

and

```
Mouse.SetCursor(Cursors.Hand);
```

In these events for controlB, which is where the drop happens:

DragOver
DragEnter
GiveFeedback

How do I get rid of the default arrow with the little box under it while dragging over controlB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `ControlB.Cursor = Cursors.Whatever;` inside your `ControB_MouseEnter()` event handler.

You may want to limit it under an `if(e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)` condition.

Tested `MouseEnter` while `MouseLeftButton` is Pressed:

[image]

Comment: MouseEnter() only triggers if the mouse button isn't being held down.